# Difference between dotnet publish and dotnet build with publish profile properties in the project

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a simple C# project producing an executable to run as a Windows service. It's targeting net6-windows because it can open with a WinForm UI if a certain argument is passed. I need a deployable **framework-dependent** output that I can include in an installer. As I see it, I have two options.

**First** - a project and a publish profile:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
        <Platform>x64</Platform>
        <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

A publish profile stored in Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>x64</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\publish</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>False</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>False</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

To get a deployable output, I would use the following command.

`dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile`

**Second** - only a project with publish profile elements included:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
        <Platform>x64</Platform>
        <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
        <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
        <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
        <PublishSingleFile>False</PublishSingleFile>
        <PublishReadyToRun>False</PublishReadyToRun>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

To get a deployable output, I would use the following command.

`dotnet build -c Release`

I get output in two different folders now. They files on both are completely the same. Therefore I would assume I can use any of the solutions? I'm confused by this statement in the official `dotnet publish` documentation at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish).

> It's the only officially supported way to prepare the application for deployment.

If I cannot rely on the second solution, I'd like to know why exactly and see a working example for my scenario, where it would make an important difference. Note, that I only want to support one TF, one RID and always publish to file system.

Comment: If docs state that _"It's the only officially supported way to prepare the application for deployment"_ you better go with it. Also note that this statement does not equal to "`dotnet build`  is guaranteed to produce something not usable or different".